# Building $http.get request...error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, request, http-get

I have the following API that I'm trying to connect to using AngularJS $http.get. However I can't build the correct URL.

This is the API URL I want to use

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=receivedate:20040312

And this is the code I have

```
return $http.get('https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=', {
  params: {
    receivedate: val
  }
```

But my results (Error) are the following

```
GET https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=&receivedate=20040312 400 (Bad Request)
```

Can someone help me structure this correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the param is `search` not `receivedate`

```
return $http.get('https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json', {
  params: {
    search: 'receivedate:' + val
  }
```